# Indexing: Invalid default value for '[column]'

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-5.7

I am working on a 10 year old web-app (!!!)
& currently running mysql locally, version 5.7.

This is the table I am currently working on:

```
CREATE TABLE `processes_history` (
  `p_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `exec_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `feature` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `macro` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ts` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `seen` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `seen_time` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `focus` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `focus_time` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mouse` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `keyboard` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `interactive` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `interactive_time` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_seen` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(`ts`))
(
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (736695) ENGINE=MyISAM,
PARTITION p201701 VALUES LESS THAN (736726) ENGINE=MyISAM,
PARTITION p201702 VALUES LESS THAN (736754) ENGINE=MyISAM,
PARTITION p201703 VALUES LESS THAN (736785) ENGINE=MyISAM,
PARTITION p201704 VALUES LESS THAN (736815) ENGINE=MyISAM,
PARTITION p201705 VALUES LESS THAN (736846) ENGINE=MyISAM,
PARTITION p201706 VALUES LESS THAN (736876) ENGINE=MyISAM,
PARTITION p201707 VALUES LESS THAN (736907) ENGINE=MyISAM,
PARTITION p201708 VALUES LESS THAN (736938) ENGINE=MyISAM,
PARTITION p201709 VALUES LESS THAN (736968) ENGINE=MyISAM,
PARTITION p201710 VALUES LESS THAN (736999) ENGINE=MyISAM,
PARTITION p201711 VALUES LESS THAN (737029) ENGINE=MyISAM,
PARTITION p201712 VALUES LESS THAN (737060) ENGINE=MyISAM,
PARTITION p201801 VALUES LESS THAN (737091) ENGINE=MyISAM,
PARTITION pmax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE=MyISAM
);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `processes_history`
--
ALTER TABLE `processes_history`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`,`exec_id`,`feature`,`ts`),
  ADD KEY `ts` (`ts`),
  ADD KEY `exec_ts` (`exec_id`,`ts`),
  ADD KEY `last_seen` (`last_seen`);
```

I keep getting an error when adding an index to `p_id, exec_id, ts`:

```
ALTER TABLE `dbname`.`processes_history` ADD INDEX `p_id,exec_id,ts` (`p_id`, `exec_id`, `ts`);
```

> Error SQL query:
>
> ALTER TABLE `dbname`.`processes_history` ADD INDEX `p_id,exec_id,ts`
> (`p_id`, `exec_id`, `ts`) MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1067 - Invalid default value for 'ts'

Following this post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192186/on-create-index-invalid-default-value

From what I understood, using `0000-00-00` as a default value breaks the 'date' type, and that's why it's not working.

But I just couldn't understand what is the solution for this situation. Using TIMESTAMP type instead?

Is there a way to solve this problem without breaking the structure (for now at least) unit I finish the whole web-app? Many things are dependent on that table and i reeeealy don't want to do something risky to index it the way I want.

Comment: What are you using `0000-00-00` as a default value for the `ts` date column?  Just let it be nullable, and handle it appropriately.  Besides this manifestation with index being a problem, I seem to recall that there are other problems which might happen.

Comment: The minimum date is `1000-01-01 00:00:00`, so either use that as default or make the column nullable as suggested by Tim.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i would, but whoever worked on that DB before me set it to a primary key for unknown reason. That's what i get when trying to set it as NULL: `Query error: #1171 - All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead`: is that the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

Changing SQL_mode solved the problem:

I compared MySQL 5.7 and 5.6, and it seems like 5.7 has the default restrictions: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, and NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` set (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date).

And on 5.6: just `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` 
(mysql 5.6 manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting)

To get my local mysql (5.7) to work in sync with the production version (5.6) I just had to [set mysql_mode](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206583/indexing-invalid-default-value-for-column/206603#206603) to `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

You can review the [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206583/indexing-invalid-default-value-for-column/206603#206603) on db-stackexchange with more info.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to change to InnoDB -- The next release (8.0) has removed MyISAM.
- Somewhere around 5.6, the handling of default for `TIMESTAMP` changed.  Think about what values you have and what values you need.
- `PARTITIONing` rarely improves performance; what query drove you to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily making the column in question nullable also solves this issue.